Transaction Log for database is full because update file about 100mb
I try to insert the data of a file about 100mb in size by splitting it into parts, each about 65,000 characters into the sql server. The first time I insert it and the next time I update that data. When it updates again, the Transaction Log for database is full error occurs. Here's my code section
public async Task<bool> AddXmlToRawXml(string filePathOnRds, string xmlContent, int sourceId, int? fileLogId, int batchSize)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "my_connection_secret";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            int? xmlFileId = fileLogId;
            long id = await InsertFirstBlock(connection, xmlContent.Substring(0, batchSize), xmlFileId);
            for (int i = batchSize; i < xmlContent.Length; i += batchSize)
            {
                string nextBlock;
                if (i + batchSize >= xmlContent.Length)
                {
                    nextBlock = xmlContent.Substring(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    nextBlock = xmlContent.Substring(i, batchSize);
                }
                await AppendBlock(connection, id, nextBlock);
            }
            long newId = await CopyRecordFromTemp(connection, filePathOnRds, sourceId, xmlFileId);
            await connection.CloseAsync();

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}

private static async Task<long> InsertFirstBlock(SqlConnection connection, string text, int? xmlId)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", xmlId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("XmlData", text);
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [DMSDataLake].[dbo].[TempXML] (XmlFileID, XmlData) OUTPUT INSERTED.XmlFileID VALUES (@Id, @XmlData); ";
    object result = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
    return Convert.ToInt64(result);
}

private async Task AppendBlock(SqlConnection connection, long id, string text)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    string escapedXmlData = text.Replace("'", "''");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XmlData", escapedXmlData);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XmlFileID", id);
    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE [DMSDataLake].[dbo].[TempXML] SET XmlData = XmlData + @XmlData WHERE XmlFileID = @XmlFileID";
    await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
}

private static async Task<long> CopyRecordFromTemp(SqlConnection connection, string path, int sourceId, int? id)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XmlFileID", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", path);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SourceCategoryId", sourceId);
    cmd.CommandText = @"DECLARE @NewId TABLE (Id BIGINT);

                    INSERT INTO [DMSDataLake].[dbo].[RawXML] (FilePath, XmlData, LoadedDateTime, SourceCategoryId, Status, ErrorMessage)
                    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @NewId
                    SELECT @FilePath, CONVERT(xml, XmlData), GETDATE(), @SourceCategoryId, 'Processed', NULL
                    FROM [DMSDataLake].[dbo].[TempXML]
                    WHERE XmlFileID = @XmlFileID;

                    SELECT Id FROM @NewId;
                ";
    object result = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

    return Convert.ToInt64(result);
}

Is there a way to handle the error and how I can insert the entire contents of that file into the database

Use SqlBulkCopy to insert the data into a staging table and either insert new rows to the target table or update existing rows if they really need updating. Executing a single INSERT or UPDATE per row generates a ton of log entries

@MitchWheat yes, It has a backup but I don't have permission to execute it.

SET XmlData = XmlData + @XmlData is a critical bug too - you can't just append one XML string after another. The result is an invalid document and again, lots of log entries. If you have a really large document (and 65KB is tiny) use a streaming parameter instead. With such small files though it's better to use an XML parameter. NOT partial strings

@Farley the problem isn't backups, it's the inefficient and buggy code that generates a lot of log entries for no reason. Don't use AddWithValue, use Add and specify the correct types. Check Specify XML values as parameters

@PanagiotisKanavos Can you give me an example? Thanks.

Check Specify XML values as parameters and the ADO.NET docs in general. It's faster than experimenting until something seems to not fail

You can also use streaming if you pass the parameter value as a Stream, XmlReader or TextReader. If you want to import the XML file into an nvarchar(max) instead of an xml column you can read it with var file=File.OpenText(path); and pass the TextReader as a parameter , cmd.Parameters.Add("@textdata", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = file;

The problem has more than one solution.
1.) First one is developer approach.
You can modify the code to generate less log. It is a bit tricky.
2.) Second one is database administrator approach.
Error message shows that your database transaction file set to limited
small value.
Notice your database administrator about the problem.
If it is a developer db and you can manage the db then run SSMS - Sql Server Management Studio, connect to sql server/instance
then on the db right click

select properties

increase the amount or set to unlimited.

exit with Ok, Ok.
Then run your routine - code.
After that make a full db backup.   Then if you want set log limited value to the initial
